# How do I draw a line in a LinearLayout containing other views?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've created a bar that is supposed to contain multiple views of different colors. A line has to be drawn that indicates the current position in the bar. Below is my simplified code:

```
public class Abar extends LinearLayout {
    final Paint line_paint = new Paint();
    private Context context;

    public Abar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        line_paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        setWeightSum(2000);
        setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);

        View view = new View(context);
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.yellow);
        this.addView(view, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1000));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawLine(20, 80, 100, 80, line_paint);
    }
}
```

Now, this does not seem to work. No matter if I swap the `canvas.drawLine` with `super.onDraw`, the line is not visible unless I remove the `view.setBackgroundResource`. How can I draw a line over the LinearLayout. I'd rather not use FrameLayout if possible.

Below are pictures of what I'm trying to achieve (adding a white line) on top of the bars (note: the white bar on the first picture is just exaggerated big for clearness on SO):

[image: bar]

[image: bar 2]

Comment: What is happening is that you draw a line on the LinearLayout, then you place a child on top of it. Thus the line is behind the child. I don't completely understand what you try to do, thus it is hard for me to propose a best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override dispatchDraw() instead of onDraw(). You want to draw the line *after* the child views draw (which isn't in super.onDraw).